# CSS Color Overlay on Image Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've tried other answers but I haven't got one to work with my particular set up. I can't use any ul/li set ups, so please don't suggest that. I'm trying to get a slightly transparent orange layer to show up over an image. I can't use absolute positioning, this site is built on foundation 4 and is responsive.

So far what I'm getting is a background-color under the image instead of on top of it. Originally I also wanted to have the green bar from the image done in CSS but I couldn't make that work either. I haven't been able to make it work with the image as a background for a div either, as I'd have to set the height/width with pixels and that breaks the responsive bit.

**Here's an image of what I'm trying to do:**

[image: Here's an image of what I'm trying to do.]

### HTML

```
<div>
 <div class="work-button">
   <img class="work-hover" src="http://oi41.tinypic.com/118m6fn.jpg" alt="" />
   <div class="work-sub">Web Design</div></div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.work-button {
text-align: center;
margin: 7%;
}
.work-hover:hover {
 background: rgba(229, 115, 37, 0.7);
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 transform: scale(0);
 border-radius: 20%;
 }
 .work-sub {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: "Candal", Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: -15%;
 }
```

**NOTE ABOUT ANSWER**
The selected answer does have its bugs. When you resize the page, the overlay won't resize with it. Instead it will stay at the size that it initialized at with the page. When you refresh the page again, it adjusts itself again. This isn't an issue for users, but more of something that bugs me and would be an issue with other developers/employers inspecting it. Regardless, thanks again Brandon Davis!

** UPDATE **

So it seems I was calling the onresize function twice, so it was only obeying what the second function was trying to do.

```
 window.onresize = function () {
    resizeWorkOverlays();
    resizeSmallOverlays();
 }
```

If you are trying to use this function twice, this the way I got it to work. I can't seem to repeat it a third time successfully though. Hope this helps!

**FINAL UPDATE** August 07, 2014: [See this new result functioning here.](http://jacquelynchastain.com/) I've since switched over to a 100% CSS solution for my hovers! I'll post the resulting code here soon.

Comment: Please show us an example using jsfiddle

Comment: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KdnJQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

**(UPDATE 3)**

**CSS**

```
.work-button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  padding: 0;
}

.work-hover {
    float: right;
    border: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black;
    border-radius: 20%;
}

.work-sub:hover, .work-hover:hover > .work-sub {
  background: rgba(229, 115, 37, 0.7);
  border-radius: 20%;
  /* box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px black; */
  opacity: 1.0;
}

.work-sub {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Candal", Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0.0;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  border: 6px solid #ffffff;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
 <div class="work-button">
   <img class="work-hover" src="http://cdn.dashburst.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Grumpy-Cat.jpg" alt="" />
   <div class="work-sub">Web Design</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

I ended up using Javascript to create the initial height and width of the div. Based on the height of the image so it can still be responsive. It may not be the most elegant way but it works.

```
function resizeWorkOverlays() {
    // Edit These to reflect your proper class names
    var workButtonClass = 'work-button';
    var workButtonImage = 'work-hover';
    var workButtonSub = 'work-sub';
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ///
    /// For Overlapping Border Put the Number of
    /// pixels that the border is the width of
    /// the border on the object. If unsure put '0'
    ///
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var borderWidth = 0; // Width of the border 

    var workButtons = document.getElementsByClassName(workButtonClass); // Gets All Elements with the class defined in 'workButtonClass' varible

    var fullBorderWidth = borderWidth * 2; // Accounts for border-top and border-bottom and left and right

    for (var i = 0; i < workButtons.length; i++) {

        var workButton = workButtons[i]; // Work with a single work button
        var workImage = workButton.getElementsByClassName(workButtonImage)[0]; // Gets First SubHeading In A 'work-hover'
        var workSubheading = workButton.getElementsByClassName(workButtonSub)[0]; // Gets First SubHeading In A 'work-button'

        //Sets the workSubHeading Styles
        workSubheading.style.height = workImage.offsetHeight - fullBorderWidth + "px";
        workSubheading.style.lineHeight = workImage.offsetHeight - fullBorderWidth  + "px";
        workSubheading.style.width = workImage.offsetWidth - fullBorderWidth + "px";
    }
}

window.onresize = function () {
   resizeWorkOverlays(); // This will run everytime the browser resizes
}

resizeWorkOverlays(); // This sets the overlays initially
```

You may also consider using a square image and rounding the corners with border-radius instead of using a "pre-formatted" image. Then the border radius on the overlay will match the image. Just a thought though.

UPDATED Fiddle:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bdavis27/rfXU3/)

Comment: Awesome! This is super close to what I'm trying to do. The only issue now is that I need that background-color to fit more to the size of the image, [like this](http://oi39.tinypic.com/atpyme.jpg).

Comment: I have updated my answer using the image you provided, which proved to be very helpful.

Comment: Hey this is super helpful, exactly what I'm looking for! I'm having a difficult time getting it to work on my page for some reason though... I can see it works in the fiddle but in Chrome only the image shows up and nothing happens but in Firefox the image won't even show...

Comment: I took my file completely apart and tried to see if anything else I had was affecting it. I did find out it is working-- kinda. The hover shows up as a tiny box big enough for the text, and only when I hover over the top left corner.

Comment: @Jackie - I have updated my post to address the issues you were having. I had a "transform: scale(0)" in the CSS that was rendering in firefox. As for the hover only showing up a tiny box of text, please make sure that you have the correct classes in Javascript and it should work. If you have any other issues please contact me.

Comment: @Jackie - I also tested it with multi 'work-button's and it worked as expected.

Comment: I'm not sure there's any possible way for the classes to be wrong-- I'm copying exactly what you have in the fiddle and pasting it into my document. It's still appearing as a small box in the top left corner, but it is showing up in Firefox now. I've uploaded my current project as of right now to my server [so you can get a better look](http://jacquelynchastain.com/test/index.html), but that it isn't working even by itself it makes me wonder if I'm missing something else to make this work? I know it's working in the fiddle... so I'm stumped.

Comment: @Jackie - Add Your JavaScript File at the end of the body instead of in the head. How I wrote the JavaScript is that it runs as soon as it loads the file. So it is currently running the JavaScript before the elements exist. Let me know if that works.

Comment: I've updated the file on the server now to reflect that change-- it looks like it's working now, sorry for my poor understanding of JS! However.. now it's not responsive with the site. I don't plan on having it show below 768 pixels but it needs to scale before that point and with the page. I'm gonna try to mess with it but if you have a solution, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Jackie - I got it to do what you have described. The only changes are in the JS. Simply replace your JS in the workoverlay.js file with the new code in the Updated Fiddle. (Last Link) It is tested to the best of my ability. Let me know how it turns out.

Comment: It does EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so very much for helping me through this for nearly a week! I hope that this post can help other users in the future. I'm gonna leave a comment in my code giving you credit to your twitter for helping me, if that's okay with you.

Comment: @Jackie - Awesome! I am glad I could help. I would be more then grateful if you gave me credit. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, not to burst our happy bubble but I got a problem with it not long after trying to continue the rest of the page... I'm not understanding why, but when the page is not in full screen and you hover over the work buttons, the background image behind the about section disappears for a moment and "blinks". It doesn't do it in full screen, but it does it in both firefox and chrome and even after I uploaded the files to the server. [Could you give it another look?](http://jacquelynchastain.com/test/index.html)

Comment: @Jackie - Sorry, I don't see what is happening. Everything looks fine from my side. Could you do a screencast of some sort?

Comment: I got the blinking to go away now and fixed an overlapping issue in firefox, but now I'm noticing something else strange. When you open the page and hover over one of the overlays, it loads it fine. But when you shrink the screen a bit and hover again, it loads the original sized overlay until you fresh the page. The ones below don't seem to be doing this. This isn't really a big issue other than if I'm showing someone I'd like it to act right, since the likelihood this will affect users is slim.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit confused as to what you are trying to do but I can help you with part of your question.

You can make a responsive div with CSS background image with this:

```
.responsive-image{
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: <!-- Divide the height by the width -->;
  background: url(@url) no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  max-width: 810px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful. [Here's an image of what I'm trying to do.](http://oi39.tinypic.com/atpyme.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Add an overlay `div` (or any other tag) inside `.work-button`, after `.work-hover`

```
<div class="work-button">
  <img class="work-hover" src="http://oi41.tinypic.com/118m6fn.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="work-overlay">Web Design</div>
  <div class="work-sub">Web Design</div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming you want to show it on hover so

```
.work-button:hover .work-overlay {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
}
```

Then add your style to `.work-overlay`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KdnJQ/4/

Note: Due to your image's formation I used fixed width and height values for the overlay.

Comment: This is exactly what I asking for, but.. because all of the size attributes are defined per pixel, it won't work with my responsive site. This is the main issue I am having by getting it to work and not being able to figure out how to make the size right.

Comment: Does the page enhance progressively? If so, you should consider a JS solution (update overlay width on imageLoad and window.resize)

Comment: Let me explain what my idea was, to make this a little clearer. The idea was, I could take [this image here](http://i39.tinypic.com/no7j3p.jpg) and apply layer styles to it instead of using an image, that result in the [first image shown here](http://oi39.tinypic.com/atpyme.jpg). When you hovered over the box, the green-transparent section would expand, the text would move, and the overlay would turn orange, as shown in the second image. This is just turning out to be a bit more difficult than I thought it would and I'm not even half done with my site haha.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by enhance progressively. I'm using Foundation's grid system for the responsiveness.

Comment: you can just hide the overlay on smaller screen devices, they are most likely to be touchscreen devices anyway (no mouse no hover)

Comment: Disabling these icons for under 768 pixels is doable. Regardless, your solution only works at a defined pixel size and as soon as the window is even slightly smaller it doesn't work. I would appreciate if you had suggestions to my original idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/photobooth/NASAEarth-01.jpg" alt="" />
    <img class="hoverimage" src="http://static3.depositphotos.com/1000988/123/i/950/depositphotos_1238765-Transparent-background-with-gradient-eff.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
<style>
    .image { position: relative; border: 1px solid black; width: 200px; height: 200px; }
    .image img { max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; }
    .hoverimage { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; opacity: 0.5;}
    .image:hover .hoverimage { display: block; }
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Zf5am/699/

Comment: Yes, except I'd like to do this entirely with CSS and without images if possible. Other than the first one, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your outer container (`.work-button`) to be an `inline-block` with `position:relative` instead of a block, you can add an overlay div with `position: absolute`, and make it take the dimensions of the parent with `width: 100%; height: 100%`:

```
<div class="work-button">
    <img class="work-hover" src="http://oi41.tinypic.com/118m6fn.jpg" alt="" />
    <div class="work-sub">Web Design</div>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.work-button:hover .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.work-button:hover .overlay {
     background: rgba(229, 115, 37, 0.7);
     transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
     transform: scale(0);
     border-radius: 20%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KdnJQ/5/